# img click not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

hi i have a image and i want to add a click event to this image field .

the problem is click event working on chrome , but not working on firefox

**HTML**

```
<img class="facebook_connect" src="http://localhost/elephanti2/assets/frontend/ivory/images/fb-button.png" alt="Sign up with Facebook">
```

**JQUERY**

```
jq('.facebook_connect').live('click',function(){
    alert("");
    var url= baseurl+"connections/facebook_connector/invite_friends_popup";
    window.open(url, 'Facebook', 'height=500,width=800');

});
```

in chrome the `alert` and `window.open` both work , in firefox it is not working . why is that ,please help........................

Comment: Could you include what you want to do onclick.. And in Chrome also it seems not working.. :-(

Comment: even alert(""); is not working

Comment: may i know from where you will get "baseurl"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script

```
$('img.facebook_connect').bind('click',function()
{
     alert('Clicked on the URL'+$(this).prop('src')); 
     // Write your next code here.. This will work in all browsers..
});
```

Here is the fiddle to check  http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `.bind` to a container instead of `.live`:

```
$('#cont').bind('click', function(e){  
if($(e.target).is('.facebook_connect')){  
// some actions  
})
```

By the way:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().